# Access Denied happen on a member of site owner of SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint

There

I have a SharePoint permission issue, the server is in domain environment.

I try to login by  .\localuser which is a member of site owner, but access is denied. But I can login by domain\domainuser for this site, which also is a member of site owner group.

Is there anyone could provide help on this, thanks.

Comment: local account is like `machinename\username` Also there is a q&a site special for sharepoint you ask related questions there  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks. I have post the same question on site SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the localuser is the PC name where it was created. Try adding the "COMPUTER_NAME\localuser" to the permissions.

Comment: .\ means computername\, I also try both, but get the same result. And in the site owner member list, I added computername\localuser to the list.